# ionic 2 http post service is not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

hey i m new in ionic 2 http request, and facing problem in http post services, following is my code you please see and help me to finding problem.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  data:any;
  name:any;
  error:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http:Http) {


  }
postit(){
   var headers=new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    var data = JSON.stringify({
      username: "username",
      password: "password"

    });


   this.http.post('url',JSON.stringify(data),{headers:headers})
   .subscribe(res=>{
     this.data=res.json();
     this.name=this.data.userId;
     console.log(res.json());
   },
    (err)=>{
      this.error=err;
      console.log("some error:",err);
    });
 }


}
```

url is of login page which need credentials. Is this code fine specially json data object.
please help me i have wasted my 4 days in this problem.
thank you.

Comment: And what is the problem exactly?

Comment: i got error in console== net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Answer (score 1):

You are calling JSON.stringify twice - once when you create the data and once when you send the POST. Remove the second one and leave only 'data'.

Comment: still i get error in console: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Comment: is the method of making an json object ok or not?